# Black out application window on KDE Plasma after long uptime

Tags: linux, kde, gtk, qt, kwin

After using for a long time, application window fails to render application windows.

## Problem:

- application screen sometimes blacks out (Attached image)
- occurs in any application (Chrome, Thunderbird, Alacritty, KSettings, Slack, Discord, ..)
- rendering collapsed but the function is alive (terminal application accept commands, Chrome can connect(checked via wireshark))

[image: Window collapse on KDE]

## Condition & How to reproduce

1. after booting up for a several days (about 100 hours)
2. (work as usual)
3. operate window (raise, expand, shrink)
4. sometimes screen blacks out

Actually, I cannot find how to reproduce except long uptime. This problem doesn't occur in first few days.

## Error:

```
# journalctl -b  
Jan 31 08:49:59 arch-desktop kernel: Linux version 6.1.8-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230111, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.40) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue, 24 Jan 2023 21:07:04 +0000
...
Feb 03 20:40:39 arch-desktop plasmashell[339482]: [339515:339515:0203/204039.778323:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, format: RED_8, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
Feb 03 20:40:39 arch-desktop plasmashell[339482]: [339515:339515:0203/204039.845182:ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(575)] Could not find SharedImageBackingFactory with params: usage: Gles2|Raster|DisplayRead|Scanout, format: RG_88, share_between_threads: 0, gmb_type: shared_memory
```

## Memory usage

Seems to be healthy

```
$ sudo nvidia-smi
Tue Feb  7 15:35:14 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.05    Driver Version: 525.85.05    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:07:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8    28W / 270W |   4288MiB /  8192MiB |     47%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

## Environment

- OS: Arch Linux (Kernal: 6.1.8)

  ```bash
  $ uname -a
  Linux arch-desktop 6.1.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue, 24 Jan 2023 21:07:04 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- Desktop: KDE Plasma (5.26.5)

  ```bash
  $ plasmashell --version
  plasmashell 5.26.5
  ```

## Question

Where is the problem occurs on (or how to find) ? Is this a kernel bug or kwin bug ?

I'm really annoying for this problem, and I can use my time for this problem. But I cannot find where is the correct place to contribute, because Linux and KDE project is very big.

## Update - 2023-10-18

After a long struggle, I have found a some clue.
I compare process tree (`ps auxf`) of when the bug occurs and not occurs.
It usually looks the same, but sometimes be different like this:

```
\_ /usr/bin/kwin_x11 --replace
|   |   \_ [cat] <defunct>
```

When I restart the process, the problem resolved without logout.

so, the following command is the trick for this problem.

```
kwin_x11 --replace
```

Comment: idk KDE at all, but that is usually a graphics out-of-memory.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your suggestion. but it seems graphic memory is sufficient (updated the question)

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Great post.  I have the same dilemna.

[blackout on right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcspQ.png)

It's very inconsistent, but seems to accumulate once it starts.  I remedied this with the process manager,  and appreciate your suggestion with  `kwin_x11 --replace`

I use brave and firefox often simultaneously and it seems to ravenge firefox windows worst.  The browser itself still visible but the viewport contents blacked out, or the right click menu.

I'm going to do an update today, let you know if that improves, as I'm running a raw install:
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
Memory: 23.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960/PCIe/SSE2
NVIDIA-driver-525

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCFll.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1224382)